# Returning result of stbi_load function and using it for glTexImage2D causes memory violation

Tags: c++, opengl, glteximage2d

I've a problem with the stbi library and I thought, maybe you have an idea why this isn't working. I have declared a function like this:

```
bool LoadTextureFile(std::string file, unsigned char ** pixel_data, int * width, int * height, int * n);
```

In this function I get the result of stbi_load directly saved in the *pixel_data variable:

```
*pixel_data = stbi_load(file.c_str(), width, height, n, 0);
// Do some more stuff till return
return true;
```

So, now my pixel_data pointer points to the memory of the result of stbi_load. Now I wanna use this result with the glTexImage2D method in my previous function. This function calls the LoadTextureFile method before calling the glTexImage2D method of OpenGL like this:

```
bool LoadTexture(...)
{
  int tex_width, tex_height, tex_n;
  unsigned char * pixel_data    = NULL;
  LoadTextureFile(filename, &pixel_data, &tex_width, &tex_height, &tex_n);
  // Do something special ...
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, tex_width, tex_height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &pixel_data);
  stbi_image_free(&pixel_data);
  // ...
}
```

But if I do it like that, then I get a memory violation message at the point of calling the glTexImage2D. 
If I move this whole magic into the LoadTextureFile, after loading a new texture file with stbi_load, then it works:

```
bool LoadTextureFile(std::string file, unsigned char ** pixel_data, int * width, int * height, int * n)
{
  unsigned char * = = stbi_load(file.c_str(), width, height, n, 0);
  // Do some magic ...
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 80, 80, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixel_data); 
  stbi_image_free(pixel_data);
  return true;
}
```

Can someone tell me why I get this message and how to solve this problem?

I guess, it is a matter of keep the reserved memory safe, but I'm not really sure, how to solve it. I tried this in a simple console application before, and there it works.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
unsigned char * pixel_data    = NULL;
[...]
glTexImage2D(..., &pixel_data);
```

is certainly not what you want. You are using the *address* of the pionter to your pixel data, not the *value* of the pointer, so you are basically telling the GL to use some random segment of your stack memory as source for the texture. It should be just

```
glTexImage2D(..., pixel_data);
```

In your second variant, what actually happens is unclear since the line

```
unsigned char * = = stbi_load(file.c_str(), width, height, n, 0);
```

just doesn't make sense and will never compile. So I assume it is copy and paste error when writing the question. But it is hard to guess what your real code would do.

Comment: Thank you, I don't know why I wrote "&pixel_data". I guess, after looking for so long for an error of my code makes me blind after some hours of searching. (-;

Comment: And yeah, "unsigned char * = = stvi_load(...);" is nonsense. It must be "unsigned char * pixel_data = stvi_load(...);". Simple copy and paste error. (;

Comment: There is another question I have, but I don't know if I should start a new topic: Is it better to use glTexImage2D or should I use gluBuild2DMipmaps? 
I tried with the last method, but it never worked for me ... /-:

Comment: @MANiC: `glTexImage2D` and `gluBuild2DMipmaps` are different things. The first use specifies a single level, while the latter builds the whole mipmap pyramid. The glu stuff is deprecated and should not be used with modern GL, but it should still work. I don't know why it doesn't in your case. You should probably open another question if you  have some issue with it.